# Every way to split a list in half in python without duplicates

Tags: python

I have a list of unique items, such as this one:

```
myList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

I want to find every possible way to split this list in half. For example, this is one way:

```
A = ['g','b','j','d','e']
B = ['f','a','h','i','c']
```

The first thing I thought of was to find all the combinations of 5 items from the list, and make this be sub-list `A`, and then everything else would be sub-list `B`:

```
for combination in itertools.combinations(myList, 5):
    A = combination
    B = everything_else()
```

This however does **not** work, as I will get every result twice. For example, if one of the combinations is `['a','b','c','d','e']` then, from this loop, I will get:

```
A = ['a','b','c','d','e']
B = ['f','g','h','i','j']
```

But then later on, when the combination `['f','g','h','i','j']` comes up, I will also get:

```
A = ['f','g','h','i','j']
B = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

For my purposes, two sets of combinations are the same, therefore I should only get this result once. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** And to clarify, I want every single possible way to split the list (without any element appearing in both `A` and `B` at the same time, of course).

Comment: So the lists would be random?

Comment: @U10-Forward I made my question a bit more clear, I need a method to generate every single possible way to do this split. The order does not matter, the elements are unique and should only appear in one of the two sub-lists. I should not get the same set of combinations twice (which is the part that is making this difficult for me).

Comment: My initial instinct was to throw both halves (A and B) into a set and then return a set of sets.

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis Nope, hence why I used combinations and not permutations

Comment: What if you have an odd number of elements in list? How do you want to split then?

Comment: @Austin That would be the next step in this problem, which is defining the length of each list (for example, stating that A should have 6 and B should have 4 or A should have 15 and B should have 2). However I simplified it a bit in the question because this is the problem ive run into now. I guess assume an even number in the original list.

Comment: for even length you can set the counter and break the loop when the half of combination will be recieved

Answer (score 3):

Liberal application of sets can solve this quite easily:

```
def split(items):
    items = frozenset(items)
    combinations = (frozenset(combination) for combination in itertools.combinations(items, len(items) // 2))
    return {frozenset((combination, items - combination)) for combination in combinations}
```

Which works as expected:

```
>>> split([1, 2, 3, 4])
{
    frozenset({frozenset({2, 4}), frozenset({1, 3})}), 
    frozenset({frozenset({1, 4}), frozenset({2, 3})}), 
    frozenset({frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({1, 2})})
}
```

This follows your basic idea—we use the combinations of five from the original large set of items, and then get the other elements (which is easy enough with a set difference). We can then simplify down the duplicates by making the pairs sets as well, so the order doesn't matter and the two in any order are treated as equivalent. We then make the outer structure a set, which means the duplicates are removed.

The use of `frozenset` over `set` here is because mutable sets can't be members of other sets. We don't need any mutation here though, so that isn't a problem.

Obviously this isn't the most efficient possible solution, as we are still generating the duplicates, but it is probably the easiest and most foolproof way of implementing it.

This also leads pretty clearly into a simple upgrade for the later extension to the problem you give in the comments:

```
def split(items, first_length=None):
    items = frozenset(items)
    if first_length == None:
        first_length = len(items) // 2
    combinations = (frozenset(combination) for combination in itertools.combinations(items, first_length))
    return {frozenset((combination, items - combination)) for combination in combinations}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem to get the actual lists?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson If you want lists you can easily construct lists from the sets, but unless you need lists for some reason (which seems unlikely given the question specified that order doesn't matter), there isn't much point in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic idea was sound, but as you noted you were getting duplicate splits. The obvious and simplest correction is to record every split you compute and check each new split computed against those already generated. Of course, the most efficient way to record and test splits is to keep them in a set:

```
import itertools

def split(myList):
    assert len(myList) % 2 == 0
    s = set(tuple(myList))
    seen = set()
    for combination in itertools.combinations(myList, len(myList) // 2):
        A = list(combination)
        A.sort()
        A = tuple(A)
        if A in seen: # saw this split already
            continue
        B = list(s - set(A))
        B.sort()
        B = tuple(B)
        if B in seen: # saw this split
            continue
        seen.add(A) # record that we have seen this split
        seen.add(B) # record that we have seen this split
        yield (A, B) # yield next split

for s in split(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']):
    print(s)
```

Prints:

```
(('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
(('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd'))
(('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'))
```